# Check string for substring with "Wild Character"

Tags: php, substr

Is it possible to check a string for a substring plus a wild character?

I am checking a url for a substring and I know there is the substring function but I am wondering if you can use the * character?  Below is my function so far.

```
function press_getUrl(){

$valid = true;
$current_url = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
//This is where I am checking for a substring plus whatever is after.
if ($current_url == "/search/node/*"){$valid = false;}

return $valid;

}

$pressValid = press_getUrl();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need no wild characters for substring.

```
function press_getUrl(){
  return (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], "/search/node/") === 0);
}
```

However, I see no use for such a function at all. what you're trying to get?

It would make sense for me if it was at least

```
function press_check_url($check){
  return (strpos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], $check) === 0);
}
```

and then called

```
if (press_check_url("/search/node/"))...
```

but I am not sure of the use of this function.

also a note on the name. your function  return no urls. so, don't use "get" in it's name.
and don't mix naming conventions.

Comment: there are other checks in the function for other strings that I left out since my question was more about the wild card. thanks for your answer +1

Answer (score 1):

This code checks if string starts with `/search/node/`:

```
if (strpos($current_url, "/search/node/") === 0){$valid = false;}
```

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot. Use `strpos()` or similar for that example.

If you want to do more complex matching (wildcards in the middle of strings, et cetera), you can use regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

You just search for position of /search/node, if position != 0, this statements fails

```
if (0 === strpos($current_url, "/search/node/")) return false; else return true;
```

Comment: `0` is casted to `false`, and 1 parentheses is lost ;-P

Comment: @zerkms: there are three === :p

Comment: Omg, I didn't see `0 === ` in the begin! Was it in your first answer revision?! Can't believe I skipped it while read the string :-S

Comment: @zerkms: my first was 0 == strpos() ... edited in few second :p

Comment: haven't seen it, seems like I'm too tired already. Btw you still have one parentheses missed